# How to connect to an Access database remotely?

Tags: ms-access

I tried to connect with ODBC, and after the ODBC configuration was successful, the way you added external data using the local Access database could not be connected successfully.

> Error message:odbc--call failed
>   [ODBC Driver Manager]The architecture mismatch between the driver and the application in the specified DSN(#0).

The local computer is installed with 64-bit access 2016,The remote computer is installed with 32-bit access 2010.
How to solve, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. It is beyond the scope of Access which is intended to connect/link via a LAN.

You may be able to *link* those remote table, but that will only work via a very reliable and high-speed connection like a 100/100 fibre WAN.